# Dynamically classloading Scala types

Tags: scala, classloader

I have the following Scala class hierarchy:

```
abstract class BaseModule(val appConf : AppConfig) {
  // ...
}

class SimpleModule(appConf : AppConfig) extends BaseModule(appConf) {
  // ...
}

class FairlyComplexModule(appConf : AppConfig) extends BaseModule(appConf) {
  // ...
}

// dozens of other BaseModule subclasses...
```

At runtime, my app will accept a String input argument for the fully-qualified class name of a `BaseModule` subclass to instantiate, but the *code* won't know which concrete subclass it will be. So I have:

```
val moduleFQCN = loadFromInputArgs()  // ex: "com.example.myapp.SimpleModule"
val moduleClass = Class.forName(moduleFQCN)
println(s"Found ${moduleFQCN} on the runtime classpath.")
val module = Class.forName(moduleFQCN).getConstructor(classOf[AppConfig]).newInstance(appConf).asInstanceOf[BaseModule]
```

So this way, the input specifies which `BaseModule` subclass to look for on the classpath, and then subsequently, to instantiate. The first three lines above execute just fine, and I see the `println` fire. However the last line above throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    <rest of stacktrace omitted for brevity>
```

So *clearly* I'm doing something wrong when trying to create an instance of the `SimpleModule` subclass, just can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: As the `InvocationTargetException` [wrapps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) a causing exception, check the actual exception thrown via `getCause()` first. Check whether `appConfig` is valid at invocation time.

Comment: The constructor of the class you're instantiating is probably throwing an exception.

Comment: From [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) for `newInstance`: `@throws InvocationTargetException - if the underlying constructor throws an exception` The code you have given is not the problem, rather there is a problem during the object creation itself.  To make more progress, you should give us all of the offending stack trace or more of your real code.

Comment: +1 to `rxg`'s comment: Alon's answer has fixed the problem you have posted; to fix your new problem, we need the inner exception from the stack trace where you posted "rest of stacktrace omitted for brevity".

Comment: You might get better ergnonomics using `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.create(fqcn, onError)`. Make it with `ScalaClassLoader.apply(classLoader)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably failing because you call `newInstance()` without any arguments, but no default constructor is found therefore the instantiation fails.

try this:

```
Class.forName(moduleFQCN).getConstructor(classOf[AppConfig])
.newInstance(appConf).asInstanceOf[BaseModule]
```

Where `appConf` is an instance of `AppConfig` and is the parameter to instantiate `BaseModule` with.

Comment: Thanks @Alon Segal (+1) I think you're on to something with the default constructor, however your example using simple strings doesn't help me out. I think another complicating factor here is that the code knows to expect *some* `BaseModule` subclass, but not until runtime. If you can change your example to use my `BaseModule` use case, and that works for me, I'll happily give you the green check! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again (+1), I think we're getting closer, but not quite there. Please see my updated question/code snippet and the new exception being produce (`InvocationTargetException`). Thoughts? Thanks again *enormously*!

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your error, can you tell me the value of "moduleFQCN" for which the exception was thrown?

Comment: It might happen because an exception is thrown from within the constructor you're trying to instantiate...